# krenew command not working : Permission Denied

Tags: linux, kerberos, byobu

I am using a Linux server to perform my simulations. The login and the file-system of the server are protected using kerberos. The file-system is supported using NFS.

Since my simulations take a lot of time to run, my ssh sessions used to hang regularly.
So, I have started running my simulations in byobu (similar to screen).

In order to make sure that my kerberos session remains active, I am using the krenew command.

I have entered the following command in my .bash_profile file. (I am sure that it is called for every login)

```
killall -9 krenew 2> /dev/null
krenew -b -t -K 10
```

So everytime I ssh to the server, I kill the existing krenew command. Then, I spawn a new krenew command -b (which runs in background), -t (I forgot why I was using this option !), and -K 10 (It must run after every 10 minutes and refresh the kerberos cache).

When I run the simulations, It runs for 14 hours and then suddenly, I am getting error for reading file **Permission Denied**

Is the command that I am running incorrect ??

Comment: You really need automatic ticket renewal. Contact your system administrator.

Comment: What is the max renewal time of a ticket? Would `k5start` be a better option? It usually comes in the same package.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am the system administrator. What should the system administrator do in this case ?? I am not overly bothered about security. My main aim is to get my script running.

Comment: @84104 What is the primary difference between k5start and krenew ?? I guess both the programs are renewing tickets only right ??

Comment: @prathmesh.kallurkar `man k5start`

Answer (score 0):

You might not be getting renewable tickets by default. Check the flags on the ticket using

klist -f ( MIT )

or

klist -v ( Hiemdal )

if you don't have renewable or R in the flags, use the -r option to kinit to get a renewable ticket. If you are getting a renewable ticket, it's more than likely that you aren't renewing the same ticket every time.

On linux kerberos tickets are files in /tmp and every login session gets a different file. I'd suggest you use kstart instead to start your job with it's own ticket and a daemon to manage that ticket.

Comment: It is showing a R flag. The flags are : FPRT. I have actually found a hack for this solution. I use script in my client machine logs into the server machine every 20 minutes using sshpass tool. However, I would still prefer a cleaner solution for kerberos.